# Composite Primary Keys in Rails still being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, composite-primary-key

I've set up a database that has composite primary keys for Ruby on Rails. Creating the migration works, but when I start to seed the database, I still get a warning that "Active Record does not support primary keys." and that the "Composite primary key is ignored." even after I've installed the composite_primary_keys gem, and included `require 'composite_primary_keys'` into the `environments.rb` file.

Any thoughts as to why the composite primary key is still ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found the work-around to this. For every model that I had that has composite primary keys, I included `require 'composite_primary_keys'` on the start of the class. Seems to work for me.